# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_3_input to have shape (33,) but got array with shape (34,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am taking the course -- Intro to Deep Learning from Kaggle.com. When I run the code

```
early_stopping = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
patience=10,
min_delta=0.001,
restore_best_weights=True,
)

history = model.fit(
    X_train, y_train,
    validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid),
    batch_size=512,
    epochs=1000,
    callbacks=[early_stopping],
    verbose=0, # hide the output because we have so many epochs
)
```

I get this error.

```
Error when checking input: expected dense_3_input to have shape (33,) but got array with shape (34,)
```

[full code](https://www.kaggle.com/ryanholbrook/binary-classification). Please help me explaining the error. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please include the code for the model.

Comment: What is the size of your X_train, y_train, X_valid and y_valid?

Comment: I took a look at the link you mentioned. It looks the dataset really has 34 features and the output is binary. So maybe they made a mistake and the `input_shape` should be equal to `34`

Comment: It's working now. There is an empty feature in the dataset. I didn't drop it. Without dropping it, input_shape should be 34 as there are 34 features in the dataset. Now, by dropping the empty feature, everything is working fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Writing the answer in the answer section, even though its present in comment section for the benefit of the community.

> There is an empty feature in the dataset. I didn't drop it. Without dropping it, input_shape should be 34 as there are 34 features in the dataset. Now, by dropping the empty feature, everything is working fine.